# JS closure with ajax (async:false)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have some problem with closure,

tool.js

```
var kTool = {};
kTool = (function() {
    var test = function(checkThis) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "post",
            dataType: "text",
            url: "check.php",
            data: {
                checkThis: checkThis
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result != 1) {
                    console.log("false");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    console.log("true");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        })
    }
    return { test: test};
}());
```

and

front.php

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    if (!kTool.test(checkThis)) {
        alert('OOPS something seems wrong！');
        document.getElementById("checkThis").focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dosomthing.php",
            data: {
                successData: successData
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log("it works!");
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

in the tool.js 
the result will return true/false and log what it will return

if it return true then front.php will execute the else part

if it return false then front.php will execute if part

but truth is, even the log say "true" it won't execute else ,

wonder what's wrong with the code and need some help to figure it out.

Comment: ktool is undefined, because your IIFE doesn't return anything - and `var kTool = {};` remains as an empty object, because you don't add anything to it ... the scope of `function test` is within the IIFE ... and finally, **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience**

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55fq6gw8/1/) may be what you want, but still, you shouldn't do it like that at all

Comment: oops that was a mistake ! but if use async it will always execute if part because the ajax is handling the data and not return wt i want. 
(im not really good at english so hope u know wt i want to say)

Comment: what you're saying is, you don't know how to use asynchronous code ... did the fiddle help at all? - or maybe [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55fq6gw8/2/)

Comment: they mean what `return` does in fucntions

Comment: see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55fq6gw8/3/) for asynch code

Comment: oh! i forget to add return part in my closure

Comment: ok so return function(result){} will return the result what return $.ajax did? true if result == 1 and false if result != 1.